# Angular.js - will this directive cause a memory leak?

Tags: angularjs, memory-management, angularjs-directive

I have a directive below and wondering if this will cause a memory leak when the component gets removed from the DOM. Angular does so much shit 'under the hood' that I can't tell if JS/Angular GC will take care of this. (And I am still trying to understand the JS Profiler in Chrome Tools to be able to figure this out myself ). So, anyone with this type of experience can answer this ?

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDir', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                 someEvent:'@'
            },
            transclude: 'element',
            template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
                return '<div class="">' +
                    '<div ng-transclude ng-click="blah()" class=""></div>'
                    '</div>';
            },
            link: function (scope, el) {  

                scope.doSomething = function(){
                  .....
                }

               scope.$on(scope.someEvent, scope.doSomething);                             

            }
        }
    }]);
```

Will the above code cause a memory leak when the element is removed from dom ?  I mean I know I could easily enhance this to add a $destroy event: IE:

```
var unregister = scope.$on(scope.someEvent, scope.doSomething);  
 scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
          unregister();                    
});
```

But is this additional step necessary or does Angular take care of this anyways ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that step, when the scope is destroyed all listeners on it will be destroyed as well.

Comment: only $on will be cleaned up. any jQuery.on calls you have to cleanup yourself.